# Lisp unit testing issue with lisp-unit

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, common-lisp, lisp-unit

I'm trying to use [lisp-unit](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/325/readings/lisp-unit.html#overview).

I could install lisp-unit with [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org): `(ql:quickload "lisp-unit")`.

Following the instructions in the lisp-unit homepage, I could define a function and make `define-test`.

```
(defun greater (x y) (if (> x y) x y))

(use-package :lisp-unit)
(define-test greater
  (assert-equal 2 (greater 1 2))
  (assert-equal 2 (greater 2 1))
  (assert-equal -1 (greater -5 -1))
  (assert-equal 0 (greater -2 0))
  (assert-equal 3 (greater 3 3))
  )
```

However, when I try to execute the `(run-tests greater)`, I get this error messages.

```
EVAL: variable GREATER has no value
   [Condition of type SYSTEM::SIMPLE-UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

Backtrace:
  0: [1956] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):
       | ~ SWANK::*SLDB-STEPPING-P* <--> NIL
  1: [1953] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):
       | ~ SWANK::*SLDB-LEVEL* <--> 7
  2: [1950] frame binding variables (~ = dynamically):
       | ~ *PACKAGE* <--> #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP-USER>
```

What might be wrong? This is the full source code that I used:

```
(ql:quickload "lisp-unit")
(use-package :lisp-unit)

(defpackage :bob
(:use :common-lisp)
  (:export #:greater))

(in-package bob)

(defun greater (x y) (if (> x y) x y))
(lisp-unit:define-test greater
  (assert-equal 2 (greater 1 2))
  (assert-equal 2 (greater 2 1))
  (assert-equal -1 (greater -5 -1))
  (assert-equal 0 (greater -2 0))
  (assert-equal 3 (greater 3 3))
  )

(lisp-unit:run-tests greater)
```

### ADDED

This is working test code:

```
(ql:quickload "lisp-unit")
(use-package :lisp-unit)

(defun greater (x y) (if (> x y) x y))
(define-test test-greater
  (assert-equal 2 (greater 1 2))
  (assert-equal 2 (greater 2 1))
  (assert-equal -1 (greater -5 -1))
  (assert-equal 0 (greater -2 0))
  (assert-equal 3 (greater 3 3))
  )

(run-tests '(test-greater))
```

Comment: I did the same steps that you've described in your question and didn't get an error. Have you done anything else in between, like switching packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation at http://github.com/OdonataResearchLLC/lisp-unit/wiki you could use either

```
(lisp-unit:run-tests '(greater))
```

or

```
(lisp-unit:run-tests :all)
```